# Поменять перевод текста для случая, когда не было изменений репутации за день

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, репутация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В оригинале там **There were no net reputation changes on this day**. Не пойму, откуда вообще **суммарное** в переводе взялось.

Предлагаю заменить просто на:

> В этот день не было изменений репутации

Answer (score 1):

Это «суммарное» взялось из «net». И я предлагаю его оставить как есть. Суть здесь в том, что в течение дня репутация может меняться, но итоговая за сутки остаётся прежней. Часто такое можно наблюдать в ситуациях, когда голосуешь «против» на некотором ответе (за это снимают 1 балл репутации), а ближе к концу серверных суток участник, давший тот ответ, решает его удалить. Таким образом минус этот откатывается, но тем не менее он хорошо виден в посуточной репутации. Поэтому-то здесь и фигурирует «суммарное», то есть изменения репутации были, но они погасили друг друга и вышли в ноль. И если это слово убрать, предложение не будет соответствовать действительности.

В качестве альтернативной версии можно заменить на что-то вроде «Суточная репутация не изменилась», может быть так будет очевиднее, хотя я и не настаиваю.

Comment: В смысле, тут «net»  - это как "нетто"? Я думал, что подразумевалось "нет изменений репутации в этой сети/сайте".

Comment: @Suvitruf когда не было вовсе изменений репутации даже нуля не отображается в этой форме. Зачем выделять строчку, если участник просто не получал изменений репы? Переводим «net» как «нет» ;)

Comment: В любом случае "не было суммарного изменения" это что-то странное (`0` и `null` это разные значения все-таки). Было бы понятнее, например, "Суммарное изменение за этот день равно 0"

Comment: @АндрейNOP в любом случае нечто «суммарное» должно остаться в тексте сообщения.

Comment: «Суточная репутация не изменилась» — кстати, вроде и нравится, но тут термин "Суточная репутация" странный, у нас такого понятия, вроде, нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP [минимум за неделю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users) :)

Comment: "Репутация за *период*" это несколько другое, "Суточная репутация" же звучит как некое понятие

Comment: @АндрейNOP суть то же самое что и «репутация за сутки»

Comment: Для меня — нет, но, возможно, я [язык не чувствую](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=46731584#46731584) :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP прям как после зубного :)